# How to quit an iPython notebook debug session?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am using iPython notebook, with the `%%debug` command.
My code performs a loop, in which I set some break point.
Now I can't seem to stop the loop with 'CTRL+C' (works in the regular ipython).

For example, let's say I have some loop with an `ipdb.set_trace()` inside. Now if I hit the 'C' key the loop continues to the `ipdb.set_trace()`, with no option from the user the exit the loop with 'CTRL+D/C'.

How can I exit such a loop?

Comment: Can you give an exact example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I updated my Question, as you can clearly see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use "ctrl+d" to delete the cell..

or to quit the debug mode just do `exit()`

note: it is not recommended to delete the cell if there is importent code

Comment: I just successfully used `exit()` in my Jupyter (formerly iPython) notebook (on a Mac) to get out of a debug session.

Comment: whats the point of the "ctrl +d" thing? i dont see how can that help to work efficiently

Comment: I don't think deleting the cell works. It may leave you hanging with a kernel in a debugger session, but unable to access it. Does you know for sure that it exits the debugger session and you're consistently able to continuing running other code? If so, what version are you using?

Answer (score 10):

You can write `exit()` to quit debug mode.